# Php condition inside CSS rules

Tags: php, css

I have a php variable called `MULTILANGUE`with a value define as true if the website has many languages and false if not.

The thing is I am using css files where I have some links like this

```
.fabricant .scroll:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 18px;
  background: url("../assets/img/picto/arrow-down.svg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

But the link is not the same depending if multilangue is true or false.

So I would like to make a condition for the url inside this css but I don't know how I can do that.

The obvious solution would be having a css file for both cases... but this would be redundant with a lot of duplicated code which is really bad.

Comment: why would have a lot of dupe code? You have one main.css file and then something like main.en.css which contains one line: `.fabricant {background: url(); }` ?

Comment: why dont  just add custom css class to generated html? i mean if `MULTILANAGUE` is true you render you html with something like `<body class="multi">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious solution is to have two CSS rules for the different backgrounds, and adding the appropriate class to elements dynamically in PHP. I repeat: you don't want dynamically generated CSS files.

```
.fabricant .scroll:before {
  ...
  background: url("../assets/img/picto/arrow-down.svg") no-repeat center center;
}

.fabricant.multilang .scroll:before {
  background-image: url("../assets/img/picto/arrow-up.svg");
}
```

```
<div class="fabricant <?php if ($isMultiLang) echo 'multilang'; ?>">
```

Comment: This might be what I'm going to do. But it's not that good considering maintenance. Adding the css rule in the css file is fine. But that means swap all class to class-multilangue on many website; where a condition inside the css will prevent those modifications. But if you tell me it's not possible I guess I'm going to do this.

Comment: Well, it's *possible*, but it's insane. You will have to modify *something* about each file anyway, and this is the sanest way to do it. Note that you don't have to add the class to each individual element; you could just add it to the body and use a selector like `body.multilang .fabricant .scroll:before`.

Comment: You could also properly use HTML `lang` attributes and something like `.fabricant:lang(es) ...`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang

Comment: How should I do the trick for a rule like `@font-face { src: url("../assets/fonts/google/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2") }`  ?

Comment: Why would you conditionally import an entirely different icon set? Presumably you'd conditionally display different icons from that icon set, not switch out the icon set, no?

Comment: It's not that it is a different one. It's about the url path which is  valid only if the website is multilangue but wrong if there is only one language.

Comment: Uhm… is this entire thing about relative URL imports? You just need to write `url(/assets/fonts/...)` instead of starting with a path relative to the current document, and all your problems are solved.

Comment: I know it's the solution, but I don't have a single website to maintain. So I can't set some with ../assets and some others with /assets/. I want this to be clean and if one day a website goes from unilangue to multilangue nothing will change in the css. I will just change the class of the element.

Comment: Your solution works fine with custom class but with @font-face i'm not sure i can do this.

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't has conditionals, you can use different classes so depending your variable you can call...

```
.fabricant.es .scroll:before {
...
}
```

or

```
.fabricant.en .scroll:before {
...
}
```

and use different content in each class..

Answer (score -1):

You could embed different css files depending on your MULTILANGUE variable:

```
 <link href="<?= MULTILANGUE?'multilangue.css':'non_multilangue.css' ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

and in each css file you can put the url directive, changing it for multilanguage or not:

```
.fabricant .scroll:before {
  background: url("../assets/img/picto/arrow-down.svg") no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: why -1 whitout explaining?

Comment: not from me by the way. But for your solution I wont do it because that means duplicate a lot of code from multi no non_multi where I should have only a few differences. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You shouldn't duplicate all code, but just the part interested by MULTILANGUE variable